# MeteorJs: Is it possible to access the filesystem client-side?

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to read a text file line by line and I was wondering if it could be done in Meteor. I read there's a `Meteor.require('fs')`, but it only works server-side. I also tried adding a smart-package with `Npm.require('fs')`, but again, it only works server-side.

What other choices do I have? Is there a way I can read a file line by line client-side in Meteor?

Comment: Client side javascript has its own file handling capacity which you can use.  See here - http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/.

Comment: That's how I tried to make it work at first, but it seems it wasn't working due to a typo. (I was using `readDataAsText` instead of `readAsText`). I got it to work now. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't access any NPM packages on Meteor's client side.

Comment: Does the file you're trying to read reside on the client machine or on the server?

Comment: It was on the client machine. In the end, I used this: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/ I now know it's sandboxed for security reasons, so the user has to select a file himself in order for me to read it via Javascript. :)

Answer (score 0):

Update: sorry, misread the question, thought it was about server-side.

The Meteor way would be to put your files you want to access on server to the `/private/` folder of your project and then use [Assets API](http://docs.meteor.com/#assets) to access them. It is the least hassle case if you want to access text or binary files you want to bundle with your app from the start of application (not for dynamically loaded files, for that you might want to use filepicker of S3).

Answer (score 0):

There is a file system API for client side Javascript, but it is entirely sandboxed for security purposes.